# Change color management preferences in maya standalone

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I have encountered a problem when changing color managmenet preferences in maya standalone. Is there a way to change these setting since opening a viewport is impossible in standalone mode?
I'm also looking for a way to change the lighting settings this way if possible.
thanks

For some reason when I change sth (like the view transform), the default value stays the same and does not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
mel.eval('colorManagementPrefs -edit -cmEnabled 1;')
```

This might work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).